# How to use d3.js to visualize a JSON tree graph?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, networkx

## tl;dr

- How to make [Radial Tidy Tree](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) work with JSON tree data from [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html)'s `node_link_data(G[, attrs])` or `tree_data(G, root[, attrs])`?
- How to make [D3 Cluster Dendrogram](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-cluster-dendrogram) work with JSON tree data from [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html)'s `node_link_data(G[, attrs])` or `tree_data(G, root[, attrs])`?
- How to make [D3 Tidy Tree](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-tidy-tree) work with JSON tree data from [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html)'s `node_link_data(G[, attrs])` or `tree_data(G, root[, attrs])`?

The examples don't use the JSON format, but a CSV-style input.

## The long version

Hi,

I am using Python and networkx to generate graph data (which is mostly tree-like). I can export the data to JSON using the networkx functions mentioned on [their page](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/json_graph.html):

- `node_link_data(G[, attrs])` : Return data in node-link format that is suitable for JSON serialization and use in Javascript documents.
- `adjacency_data(G[, attrs])` : Return data in adjacency format that is suitable for JSON serialization and use in Javascript documents.
- `tree_data(G, root[, attrs])` : Return data in tree format that is suitable for JSON serialization and use in Javascript documents.

The documentation of networkx explicitly mentions:

> tree like in the d3.js example https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550

However, the [linked example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550) doesn't seem to make use of the JSON tree format, but uses a [`csv` type of input](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063550#flare.csv). As my javascript-skilz are essentially zero, I do not understand how to make Mike Bostock's example work with the JSON data I have. Can you help?

## Example JSON

```
{
  "issueid": "3295658",
  "issuetype": "Portfolio-Epic",
  "status": "In Progress",
  "pirank": 24,
  "id": "ATROB-2523",
  "children": [
    {
      "issueid": "3288189",
      "issuetype": "Epic",
      "status": "Implementation",
      "id": "ATTDATA-233",
      "children": [
        {
          "issueid": "3305730",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Implementation",
          "id": "ATTDATA-363"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3305723",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Open",
          "id": "ATTDATA-361"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3301728",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Open",
          "id": "ATTDATA-336"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3297381",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Closed",
          "id": "ATTDATA-300"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3295913",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Review",
          "id": "ATTDATA-290"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3295893",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Open",
          "id": "ATTDATA-289"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3291658",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Closed",
          "id": "ATTDATA-256"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3291653",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Closed",
          "id": "ATTDATA-255"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3291530",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Open",
          "id": "ATTDATA-253"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3290232",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Open",
          "id": "ATTDATA-247"
        },
        {
          "issueid": "3287061",
          "issuetype": "Task",
          "status": "Resolved",
          "id": "ATTDATA-226"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "issueid": "3300899",
      "issuetype": "Request",
      "status": "REJECTED",
      "id": "ATI-1478"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you share an example output json for a simple tree (say 3-8 nodes)?

Comment: if your python skills are good then a fast read on the mozilla website on how to do it in Javascript would not be a problem.

Comment: @rioV8 : Sorry, I (re-)started learning python only two weeks ago.... :/ Could you add a link to where I could start reading? Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mike Bostock's linked example converts CSV data into hierarchical form using [d3.stratify](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#stratify):

```
var stratify = d3.stratify()
    .parentId(function(d) { return d.id.substring(0, d.id.lastIndexOf(".")); });

[... later in the code...]


var root = tree(stratify(root));
```

In your case, your data is already in hierarchical form, so you can run it through [d3.hierarchy](https://github.com/d3/d3-hierarchy/blob/master/README.md#hierarchy) to convert it into a d3-type hierarchy and then create a chart with it:

```
var root = tree(d3.hierarchy(data));
```

You will also need to change the function that pulls in the data from `d3.csv` to `d3.json`:

```
// assume your data is in `data.json`
d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
```

So the top of the script now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height"),
    g = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width / 2 + 40) + "," + (height / 2 + 90) + ")");

var tree = d3.tree()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, 300])
    .separation(function(a, b) { return (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth; });

d3.json("data.json", function(error, data) {
  if (error) throw error;

  var root = tree(d3.hierarchy(data));
```

[Here's a .block](https://bl.ocks.org/ialarmedalien/840c4d461a541903e9168fadcb1250d9) with the tree from the JSON data you supplied above.

Comment: Thanks, @i-alarmed-alien .  This answer helped me directly to solve my problem (despite the fact that I was distracted from it for months... ) Thanks for posting, especially with the .block showcasing the implementation!